# component is not defined, Vue

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

Vue component is not defined: it shows in console log after I moved the button from index.blade.php to FollowButton.vue, vue 3, laravel 8. You can see the code below.

Here is the `app.js`

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';

components.forEach(component => app.component(component.name, component))

const app = createApp({}).component(
  'follow-button',
  require('./components/FollowButton').default
);

app.mount('#app');
```

And here is the `FollowButton.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" >Follow</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reflection on your code

You have created an **empty** application using `const app = createApp({})`. Within this empty application, you declared the `follow-button` component using `app.component('follow-button', FollowButton)`.

Now, you want to use the component, but there is no place to do so because the application you created is "empty" as indicated by the empty object `{}`.

#### Solution # 1

Instead, you can create an `App.vue` file that will serve as the foundation for your Vue application: `const app = createApp(App)`.

[Vue Playcode for Example](https://playcode.io/1511917)

```js
// app.js

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import FollowButton from './components/FollowButton.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

app.component('follow-button', FollowButton);

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<!-- App.vue - Example... -->
<template>
  <h1>Hello Vue 3</h1>
  <follow-button />
</template>
```

#### Solution # 2

Alternatively, you can simply declare a `template` where you can use the `follow-button` component.

[Vue Playcode for Example](https://playcode.io/1511930)

```js
// app.js

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import FollowButton from './components/FollowButton.vue';

const app = createApp(FollowButton);

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Appreciate it a lot but is still did not work, I have found a solution doing this way.import { createApp } from 'vue';
import FollowButton from './components/FollowButton';

const app = createApp({});

const components = [
    { name: 'follow-button', component: FollowButton }
];

components.forEach(component => {
    app.component(component.name, component.component);
});

app.mount('#app');

Comment: The problem again with `createApp({})` --> generated "empty application", read again my answers.

Comment: If you need more components in a vue app, then you need my "solution # 1". You can import every component to app, and can use it in App.vue file.

Comment: Need to add your application code to "createApp() function", thats render your application. You can't call components outside the `createApp()`. You can declare more `createApp()` with "solution # 2" for every component.